# Can I attain to Satori in Walking Meditation?

Tags: personal-practice

I like the walking meditation more than doing sitting Zazen. I want to ask if satori is possible while walking?

Comment: You can attain satori while sweeping the floor. But sounds like you need to study more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I like** walking meditation more than doing sitting Zazen.

The concept of egotistic self or 'I' is inseparable to doership. 'Satori' is in the understanding of non-action without understander. 'Satori' is a deep intuitive understanding of egolessness of your being devoid of any egotistic identity. Out of egolessness arrives non-action, then walking would happen without the central 'I'. Then there won't remain 'I' what to talk about its likes or dislikes?

[Huineng](http://www.shaolintemplemi.org/dajian-huineng-the-official-sixth-patriarch-of-ch%27an.html) said,

> Bodhi is no tree, 
>   nor is the mind a standing mirror bright. 
>   Since all is originally empty, 
>   where does the dust alight? 
>   Explanation: Huineng pointed out that to see the mind as a "thing" to be kept pure by constantly "sweeping away" defilements is to miss the elemental truth that mind is in itself buddha (awakened, enlightened), and is therefore inherently pure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But the walking must be done with 'empty mind' so consciousness illuminates.